# Как решить с Ripple в Lolipop

Tags: java, android

Я хочу использовать визульаный эффект ripple в Андроид от 16 API.
Стандартаня Ripple от гугла не подходит. Она поддерживает от 21 Апи. Не понятно в чем трудность добавление этой функции. Короче политику гугла не поймешь. Приходит выкручиваться.

Нашел библиотеку. compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'. У нее проблема в том что onclick работает лишь на родителя. Нельзя использовать для Родителя и для дочерних View.

Есть варианты? AppComPact Ripple такого нету). Я не нашел

Comment: В моём проекте тоже такая проблема была. Всё решил подключением Support Library. Анимации не столь изящны, как в оригинале, но лучше, чем ничего

Comment: @EgorRandomize а что за SupportLibrary? там же нету поддежки Ripple. Не понял  вас

Comment: Извиняюсь. У меня тоже `com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2`. Рипл только для Родителя и дочерних Вьюшек, верно. 

Можете в `API>=21` использовать вшитые элементы с эффектами; для `API<21` можете вызывать другую активность с элементами из этой библиотеки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет вариантов.

Там какая-то заморочка с аппаратным ускорением или с графическим драйвером, точно не помню, поэтому только с API21.
Если бы оно могло работать с ранним API, давно было бы в Support Library.

Так что никакой политики, просто техническое ограничение.

Answer (score 1):

`Ripple` в API 21 работает в `RenderThread`, который ниже 21 отсутствует. Поэтому пишите на `selector`.